# php prevent items from loading, and load with trigger

Tags: php, html

I'm rather new to programming, but I'm trying to find a way to do what is described below.

```
<body>

<div class="gallery">

<img src="photo_1.jpg">
<img src="photo_2.jpg">
<img src="photo_3.jpg">

<!-- trigger for user to load items that weren't downloaded on page load -->
<img src="photo_4.jpg">
<img src="photo_5.jpg">
<img src="photo_6.jpg">

</div>

</body>
```

I'm trying to find **PHP** functions that would, ideally, only load the first 3 **img** embeds within a certain **class/ID**, and have a clickable trigger to request the remaining **img** embeds from the server.

I don't know if this is how the typical message board software(such as **vBulletin**) handles things with "**spoiler tags**" .. as in whether or not it actually prevents loading, or just hides the content from view. Something like that, if it actually prevents loading, is what I'd like to know about.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, what? (Also, this is not something that can be done with PHP. You need javascript.)

Comment: Also, there is a way to load images upon viewport chanheing, known as [lazyload](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/).

Comment: Yeah not a PHP thing at all this is all JavaScript! @Rottingham is on the write track just take it out of inline.

Answer (score 0):

First, this has nothing to do with PHP.

The only way to prevent a page from loading the image is to not include the  tags on the page.

You could accomplish this a couple ways:

Place the last three photos inside a hidden  container and use a Javascript click event to display them when wanted, but that still loads the images when the page is loaded.

Or, you can use an AJAX call to retrieve the items only on demand. Unless they are really large images I would think the first option the best.

```
<div class="gallery">
    <img src='photo1.jpg'/>
    <img src='photo2.jpg'/>
    <img src='photo3.jpg'/>
    <a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("hidden-gallery").display="visible"'>show more</a>
    <div id="hidden-gallery" class="hidden-gallery" style="display:none">
        <img src='photo4.jpg'/>
        <img src='photo5.jpg'/>
        <img src='photo6.jpg'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I recognize that embedding CSS styles and Javascript the way I did is not the preferred method but it is there just for the examples sake.

Comment: I've already done the first suggestion for something else with JavaScript, but this is an area where I believe it should really be prevented from loading for both bandwidth and page length.

Comment: Then you will need to research AJAX and server side scripting calls as well or use Javascript to dynamically add <img> nodes to the DOM.

Comment: You don't actually need to use AJAX. If you just add the `img` tags with jquery or standard javascript page manipulation, the browser's smart enough to go out and download the required images.